# angular2 observable.fromEvent vs button click

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have some code which alternately uses both 
`<button (click)="callsomefucntion" />` and `Observable.fromEvent<MouseEvent>(button.nativeElement.'click')`

What is the difference between both of these approaches? When should i go for one to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observables` approach is more flexible. There are many many functions which you can use with Observables. It will be very good to read the [**documentation**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) by yourself.

If you want only handle the `click` and do basic things, just use button click, but if you need manipulations with the `click` event and you think you need to write much logic for that manipulations ( example: `fire the event only after some time from previous one` or `merge` your click with other `api calls` and do some manipulations with incoming data before showing in the markup), first look at the documentation of Observables, there may be methods which can help you with your logic implementation.

Order of execution when three approaches are applied.

```js
const button = $('#btn');

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('From pure callback'));

Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click')
.subscribe(() => console.log('From observable'));

button.on('click', () => console.log('From jQuery callback'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.4.3/dist/global/Rx.js'></script>
<button id='btn'>Click</button>
```

Comment: Why do we use both in a single button , on the same click event?

Comment: You need only to use one approach

Comment: What is the order of execution when both are attached to a button? on the same event?

Comment: @Jocket See code part. Which one will be attached sooner, that will be fired soon.